# regular expression doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have in the database saved data previously inserted, I need to extract a fragment to replace it, but it does not work no matter what I do, the regular expression is correct because I already tried it in other programs, please I need help.

this is the text in the database

```
administrator/history_p/1/<?php echo base_url();?>articuls/Antes
```

I need replace all before including this `<?php echo base_url();?>`

but the angulars `<>` don't want to accepted them.

this is the regular espression

```
[^\s<>]*)<(\?php echo base_url\(\);\?>
```

this is the code

```
$regexp = preg_replace("([^\s<>]*)<(\?php echo base_url\(\);\?>)", 'HI', $field)
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using.

Comment: *"the regular expression is correct"* ... you sure? At the very least it's lacking delimiters.

Comment: @CD001 The delimiters typically used in combination with regular expressions are _not_ part of the expression! They are a typical trick used by the implementations to speed up the processing of expressions. But regular expressions themselves as defined by theoretical computer science does _not_ use them and indeed there are implementations that work without them.

Comment: this is the code                                                                                  $regexp = preg_replace("([^\s<>]*)<(\?php echo base_url\(\);\?>)", 'HI', $field)

Comment: Please do _not_ add additional information here into comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it!_

Comment: @arkascha - while that may be true; try putting a regex into `preg_match` without the delimiters and see where you get ... that's what I suspect is happening. Which is why I asked if they were sure.

Comment: @CD001 Which is perfectly correct. But again that is because that specific implementation requires such delimiters. They are _not_ part of the regular expression you come up with to solve a task. You suggested the expression is "wrong" because it does not contain delimiters. That is a fallacy.

Comment: @arkascha technically you're entirely correct ... but looking at the *"From comments"* edit just added ... the problem *is* missing delimiters ;)

Comment: I use http://www.regexr.com/  with all the previous example and works perfectly

Comment: @CD001 Most likely that is correct. Because that specific regex implementation _does_ require delimiters _around_ the regular expression. There are no such delimiters in the example, so that will result in an error. Remember the older `ereg` implementation in php? That one did _not_ use delimiters for example.

Comment: @Mary Please take a close look at the `regexr.com` form you are using. Even in there the delimiters are shown...

Comment: @Mary Please take a look into your http servers error log file. You will see an error like "failed to compile regular expression". That is because you did _not_ add delimiters around your regular expression as the documentation explicitly requests.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is correct but you have to add delimiters:

```
$regexp = preg_replace("/([^\s<>]*)<(\?php echo base_url();\?>)/", 'HI', $field) 
//               here __^                           and here __^
```

There no needs to use capture groups and you have to escape the parenthesis:

```
$regexp = preg_replace("/[^\s<>]*<\?php echo base_url\(\);\?>/", 'HI', $field)
```

Answer (score 0):

For data you showed this regex works as charm

```
.*>
```